# UK License Number RUTA entity extraction

Tags: text-analysis, uima, ruta

I have been developing a proof of concept of free text analytics. The RUTA scripts which I have developed for account number, date, salutations, addresses, pin codes, name seem to work properly.

But I am stuck on one rule where I want to extract the license number in UK format from a textual paragraph. The rule I developed seems to work properly when it is alone passed as input but for some reason it fails in a text.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I have been with this issue for quite sometime.

```
       PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
       DECLARE VarA;
       DECLARE VarB;
       DECLARE VarC;

       W{REGEXP("^(?i)(a-z){2}") -> MARK(VarA)}
       NUM{REGEXP("..") -> MARK(VarB)}

       W{REGEXP("(?i)(a-z){3}$") -> MARK(VarC),  MARK(EntityType,1,3), UNMARK(VarA), UNMARK(VarB), UNMARK(VarC)};
```

The format which I am expecting is 
C - Character 
N - Number

1. CCNNCCC
2. CCNN CCC

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, I am very new to RUTA scripting. Any documentation to learn it properly would be highly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question(or problem) is not totally clear for me. Also the example script doesn't work (EntityType is not declared and the regular expressions are not valid).

I made an example script. Maybe that will help you:

[image: Simple example script]